# Invalid description in r

Tags: r

I can't understand this Error:

```
Error in file(paste(out.dir, paste("OutSam", i, "M", M, ".txt", sep = ""),  : 
  invalid 'description' argument
```

why and the code it seems right to me. Is it possible if you can explain it to me please? what I am trying to do is saving the output every time I have different loop with different sample and number of iteration.

```
M1 <- function(n){
M1list <- list()
x = rnorm(n)
av <- mean(x)
M1list$av <- av
return(M1list)
}
M2 <- function(n){
M2list <- list()
x = rnorm(n)
va <- var(x)
M2list$va <- va
return(M2list)
}
get.pred <- function(asim,ModelFun,M){
test <- list()
dat <- rnorm(asim)
if(M==1){
Model <- ModelFun(asim)
Ass <- matrix(NA,nrow=asim,ncol=1)
Y <- Model$av
Y <- Y+dat
Ass[,1] <- Y
}
else{
Model <- ModelFun(asim)
Ass <- matrix(NA,nrow=asim,ncol=1)
Y <- Model$va
Y <- Y+dat
Ass[,1] <- Y
}
test$Size <- asim
test$Ass <- Ass
return(test)
}


out.dir <- "C:/Documents and Settings/Fsaid/Desktop/R Output"
Ass.dir <- "C:/Documents and Settings/Fsaid/Desktop/R Output/Assessment"
set.pred <- function(asim,ModelFun){
for(i in asim){
for(mf in ModelFun){
M <- as.integer(gsub("\\M", "", quote(mf)))
zz <- file(paste(out.dir,paste("OutSam",i,"M",M,".txt",sep=""),sep="/"))
Ass <- file(paste(Ass.dir,paste("Asse",i,"M",M,".txt",sep=""),sep="/"))  
Pred <- get.pred(asim=i,ModelFun=mf,M=M)
out <- capture.output(Pred)
cat(out,file=zz,sep="\n",append=TRUE)
write.table(test$Ass,quote=F,file=Ass,row.names=T,col.names=NA,sep="\t")
close(zz)
close(Ass)
     }
    }
   }
Set <- set.pred(asim=c(300,500,700,900,1100),ModelFun = c(M1,M2))

drive <- "E:"
Set <- set.pred(asim=c(300,500,700,900,1100),ModelFun = c(M1,M2))
```

Comment: Vote up please I nedd support

Answer (score 1):

No error here if I just do

```
 out.dir <- 'c:/foo and bar/subdir/'
 M <- 'MMM'
 file(paste(out.dir, paste("OutSam", i, "M", M, ".txt", sep = ""))))
```

The result is:

```
  description                          class 
"c:/foo and bar/subdir/ OutSam100MMMM.txt"                         "file" 
                      mode                           text 
                       "r"                         "text" 
                    opened                       can read 
                  "closed"                          "yes" 
                 can write 
                     "yes"
```

You may need to look closely at what your `M` actually is.

Comment: thanks for the answer do you have an idea to return the integer in ModelFun.i.e If ModelFun <- M1 how can I return 1 and assign it to M. Thanks

Comment: I think you have bigger problems than that.  What are the contents of `ModelFun` , and what really happens in `for(mf in ModelFun){... get.pred([stuff...] ModelFun=mf)` ?  Also, what is `get.pred`? You should provide the library package it belongs to.

Comment: I think you make it sound it is bigger problem there is no need for the library and if you went over the code you can see what is the contents if ModelFun which is only an argument in the set.pred function to call the M1 or M2.and what happens in (mf in ModelFun) is just call different M1 and M2.

Comment: So, break it down.  Forget your code for the moment and just try building file descriptors, e.g. `foo<-file(paste('c:/foo','bar',sep='/')` and see when or what leads to an "invalid description" error.

Comment: I update the code can you please run it and let me know what do you mean by building different descriptors?

Comment: Guys you should vote me up not down. I don't understand why you vote me down

Comment: You're being downvoted because you don't appear to have gone back and read the documentation for `file` .